# php static in if statement

Tags: php, static, if-statement, variable-declaration

I have a construction like this in my config file:

```
<?php
if (true) {
    $nonstatic = 1;
    static $config = 1;
}
else {
    $nonstatic = 2;
    static $config = 2;
}

echo $nonstatic;
echo $config;
?>
```

So why the $config contains 2 if this part of the statement is false and $nonstatic contains 1? Is it a bug?

Comment: Is this the entire script, or is there more code?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better declaring the variable outside the `if` and simply assigning it a value inside? I've never seen the `static` keyword used like this, although that doesn't mean it's wrong...

Comment: Seems like last static declaration (irrespective of anything) decides the value.

Comment: @Michael, of course there is more code. This is a simplified version, describing what I am trying to reach.

Comment: @DaveRandom since it's a configuration file for a project I would like for the variable to be read-only.

Comment: @Aldekein In that case, should consider using a constant instead...

Comment: The static keyword is not really meant to be used outside a class. What i think happens is that the second "static" statement overrides the first at compile-time. As it is normally used in class declarations it is not built to support this kind of usage. What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Johan: static keyword can [definitely be used outside of classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) in PHP, by design. However, OP was incorrectly trying to use them as constants.

Comment: @webbiedave Ah tnx! Thought it was bad practice. I was right about the compile-time/scope thing though :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose this chunk is being included from a function.

Initialisations of static variables are resolved at compile-time, and [if the interpreter finds multiple initialisations, it simply takes the bottom one](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: In particular, this means that conditionals _around_ a static initialisation have no effect.